# Fetch rows with count

Tags: mysql, sql

```
--------------------------------------------------
| UserID    |   Name        | RefID              |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1         | xyz           |  1                 |
| 2         | abc           |  1                 |
| 3         | def           |  1                 |
| 4         | gij           |  2                 |
| 5         | jkl           |  2                 |
| 6         | mno           |  2                 |
--------------------------------------------------
```

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE UserID='$id' LIMIT 1 ");
$query_ref = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(ref) FROM `users` WHERE RefID='$id'");
```

Can these two queries be merged into one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT UserID, Name,
(
  SELECT COUNT(RefID) 
    FROM users 
   WHERE RefID = u.UserID
) RefCount
  FROM users u
 WHERE UserID = ?
 LIMIT 1
```

Sample output:

```
| USERID | NAME | REFCOUNT |
|--------|------|----------|
|      1 |  xyz |        3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f052/3)** demo

On a side note: learn and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with either `Mysqli` or `PDO` instead of interpolating query strings.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand you want to count number of users with a reference id. I would use this way:

```
SELECT count(*) as "counted" FROM users WHERE RefID=1
```

This will giff you the data you might want.

Regards